# RSpec: How to stub methods and method-chains

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, singleton

I have a singleton class that is accessed by a number of other classes and controllers to determine behaviour. How do I set the singleton values in my tests so I can test the behaviour. Example code below where Setting is a Singleton class, which is database backed and stores application wide settings and these settings can be changed by administrators. Floodgate is a class that accesses the settings.

```
class Setting
  def instance
    @setting ||= new
  end
end

class Floodgate
  def self.whitelist
    Setting.instance.flood_gate_whitelist
  end
end
```

Below are some tests for Floodgate which need to access the Settings database values.

```
describe Floodgate do
  let(:setting) { Class.create(Setting).instance }

describe ".whitelist" do
  it "returns a list of values on the Settings floodgate whitelist" do
    expect(Floodgate.whitelist).to eq 'google'
  end
end

describe ".allow_traffic_source?" do
  it "returns true if traffic source is on the white list" do
    expect(Floodgate.allow_traffic_source?('google')).to eq true
  end

  it "returns false if traffic source is not on the white list" do
    expect(Floodgate.allow_traffic_source?('facebook')).to eq false
  end
end
```

The first and second test above fail, because Setting.flood_gate_whitelist is nil. In the Floodgate tests, how do I set it so that it persists, atm there is no record in the d/b. I tried explicitly setting it as below and when I use create, the error response is undefined method 'create'.

```
let(:setting) { Class.new(Setting, flood_gate_whitelist: 'google').instance }
```

Answer (score 5):

Stub the message chain being called. In your case, an example would be:

```
before do
  allow(Setting).
    to receive_message_chain("instance.flood_gate_whitelist").
      and_return("google")
end
```

Now `Setting.instance.flood_gate_whitelist` anywhere in your code will return `"google"`.

Alternatively, you could stub instance methods on `Setting` like so:

```
before do
  allow_any_instance_of(Setting).
    to receive(:flood_gate_whitelist).
      and_return("google")
end
```

Go with the latter if you're sure that you're instanstiating `Setting` correctly.

Incidentally, configuration-related variables would ideally go into a `*.yml` file (e.g. `database.yml` for which database to use) that would have different values based on the current project environment (which would remove the need to stub methods, in many cases).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I fixed my issue by changing the instance method on the Singleton model to `first || new`. Your comment re correctly instantiating the model pointed me in the right direction.